# Paypal Shipping options for a non U.S merchant

Tags: paypal

I've been working on a minimalist e-commerce website where I am trying to leverage Paypal's Add To Cart and View Cart buttons for the financial aspect of this website. However, I found out if you are not a U.S merchant you are restricted on Paypal's shipping calculator by not being able to calculate shipping by weight and region.

I am looking for alternatives to making a full e-commerce site, where the users do not have to register or type in their personal information or charge a fixed shipping rate for products.

I am curious on what everyone thinks regarding the user experience of a user entering their zip/postal code into an input box and being presented with a total price by estimated shipping prices (from UPS' API, Canada Post's API), and calculating taxes by region for each product.  Otherwise, offer an option for the base product price plus a warning that the shipping and taxes are pending without specifying their zip/postal codes. If you have any other ideas, I would be glad to read them!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I typically recommend doing...gathering shipping directly from shipping carrier API's and then passing those values into the shopping cart / payment integration accordingly.

Any PayPal integration you choose would allow you to pass those details in be it Payments Standard, Express Checkout, Payments Pro, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do recommend creating a registration process for capturing the users shipping information? Or would my idea of having a simple zipcode / postal code text field to capture their location to update their shipping information be good. I like this Idea because I can delegate the rest to paypal ( e.g. account registration, financial information, etc) and then my users don't need to register to this site. Please let me know if your unsure of what I mean.

Comment: A few ways to do this.  You could use PayPal Access, for example, to let users create accounts and login to your site similar to Facebook Connect.  This would give you their info so you can calculate shipping for them while they're checking out.  

Another option would be to use Express Checkout which will return the buyer details to you via GetExpressCheckoutDetails.  Once you have that data you could go ahead and create an account for that person in your system, so again, all they had to do was sign in to PayPal.

You can calculate the shipping and then pass it into DoExpressCheckoutPayment.